# How to Replace a hash character in file?

Tags: regex, string, bash, grep

How can I remove '#' character from file

```
 File Name: /etc/ironman.d

 #dir /usr/comicon
 #dir2 /usr/individuality
 #dir3 /usr/land
```

How can I remove '#' character before dir2. There is no way to maintain line number. 
 I tried

```
 dirpath='#dir2 /usr/individuality'
 ${dirpath#/#}
```

But it only removes in $dirpath but not in actual file, if I use above method to remove '#' and add then, I get a duplicate of $dirpath without '#', but I just want single entry without '#' in the file. How do I remove # in place (before dir2)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`sed(1)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) to edit files:

```
sed -e 's/#dir2/dir2/' /etc/ironman.d
```

Comment: Is there a way using awk ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way using awk. What are you really asking?

Comment: I wanted to use awk for replacing. Thanks !

Comment: Issue is sed with sed -e 's/#dir2/dir2/' /etc/ironman.d works fine if file has only one entry but what if file has multiple entry and for dir2 with different path names?

Comment: `s/#//`  will remove the leftmost occurrence of `#` on each line.  `s/#//g`  will remove every occurrence of `#` on each line.

Comment: `sed -i` is usually pretty dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all leading #'s :

```
sed -e 's/^#*//' /etc/ironman.d
```

Answer (score 0):

An awk solution :

```
awk -F'#' '{print $2}' /etc/ironman.d
```

Comment: Or sed replacing every first # `sed -e 's/^#//' /etc/ironman.d`

Comment: awk solution will not work, when there is no `#` in the line. Or multiple `#'s`

Comment: I may not fully understand what you want but here is another awk to try `awk '/dir2/{$1="dir2"}1' /etc/ironman.d`